# getting map container is already initialized when clicking on the tabs using leaflet.js in IONIC 5

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, leaflet

Here i am trying to display the leaflet js maps in ionic 5 tabs below are my issues

1. i have 2 tabs in ionic app tab1--> map , tab2 --> some other page when i click on tab1 and go to tab 2 and after some time if click on tab1 again i am getting  error as
   **Map container is already initialized**
2. if i am tab1 and going to tab2 and again clicking on the tab1 if pinch n zoom the maps tiles are going back wards and clearing map images and showing grey area.

below is my code :

html

```
<ion-content id="mapId" style="--offset-top:0px; --offset-bottom:0px;">
</ion-content>

 // when ever a marker on map is clicked then the this below ionic content will displayed 
<ion-content class="detail-desc" id="detail-desc">  
</ion-content>
```

**type script code:**

map: L.Map;
center: L.PointTuple;

```
leafletMap() {
    document.getElementById('detail-desc').style.display = 'none';

    this.map = L.map('mapId').setView([this.Latitude, this.Longitude], 20);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(this.map);

    const myFeatureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(this.map).on('click', (e) => {
      console.log(e);
      const event = e;
      const that = this;
      this.myTest(event, that);
    });
    let marker: any;

    const availableIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: '../../assets/icon/marker-icon-2x.png',


      iconSize: [21, 34],
    });
    const unAvailableIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: '../../assets/icon/marker-icon-red.png',
   

      iconSize: [21, 34], 
    });
  

    const locationIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: '../../assets/icon/current-location.png',
 

      iconSize: [30, 30], 
    });
    
    marker = L.marker([this.Latitude, this.Longitude], { icon: locationIcon }).addTo(myFeatureGroup);
   
    for (let i = 0; i < this.mapData.length; i++) {
      if (this.mapData[i].status === 'Available') {
        marker = L.marker([this.mapData[i].locationLat, this.mapData[i].locationLong],{ icon: availableIcon ,id:this.mapData[i].Id}).addTo(myFeatureGroup);
      } else {
        marker = L.marker([this.mapData[i].locationLat, this.mapData[i].locationLong],{ icon: unAvailableIcon,id:this.mapData[i].Id }).addTo(myFeatureGroup);
      }

      marker.selectedData = this.mapData[i];
    }


  }
```

to check the gps permission

// Check if application having GPS access permission

```
      checkGPSPermission() {
        this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION).then(
          result => {
            if (result.hasPermission) {
    
              // If having permission show 'Turn On GPS' dialogue
              this.askToTurnOnGPS();
            } else {
    
              // If not having permission ask for permission
              this.requestGPSPermission();
            }
          },
          err => {
            alert(err);
          }
        );
      }
    
      requestGPSPermission() {
        this.locationAccuracy.canRequest().then((canRequest: boolean) => {
          if (canRequest) {
            console.log('4');
          } else {
            // Show 'GPS Permission Request' dialogue
            this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
              .then(
                () => {
                  // call method to turn on GPS
                  this.askToTurnOnGPS();
                },
                error => {
                  // Show alert if user click on 'No Thanks'
                  alert('requestPermission Error requesting location permissions ' + error);
                }
              );
          }
        });
      }
    
      askToTurnOnGPS() {
        this.locationAccuracy.request(this.locationAccuracy.REQUEST_PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).then(
          () => {
            // When GPS Turned ON call method to get Accurate location coordinates
            this.getLocationCoordinates();
          },
          error => alert('Error requesting location permissions ' + JSON.stringify(error))
        );
      }
    
      // Methos to get device accurate coordinates using device GPS
      getLocationCoordinates() {
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
          // resp.coords.latitude
          // resp.coords.longitude
          const latLong = {
            lat: resp.coords.latitude,
            long: resp.coords.longitude
          };
          // this.LatAndLang.push(latLong);
          console.log(this.Latitude, this.Longitude);
          this.Latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
          this.Longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
          console.log(resp);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error getting location', error);
        });
      }


loading the data on the on ion view did load


getLoadedLocations(){
    this.httpClient.get(this.endPointUrl).subscribe(data => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
      this.mapData = data;
      // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
      this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (this.Latitude) {
            this.leafletMap();
          }
        }, 5000);
      });
      // this.products = data; 
    },error => {
       console.log('Unable to get the location');
    });
  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){
    console.log('view loaded');
    this.getLoadedLocations();
    this.checkGPSPermission();
   
  }
```

Comment: Add the functions on ngOnInit instead on ionViewDidEnter, since on each page ebtry the function will be triggered since tabs is lazy loaded and thus each tab change will close the page and on open pack will open again, and the map is being cached as opened and when open again will cause this.

Comment: Ok let me give me a try